# GET Request yields 404 error when using variables in URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to create a python script that requests data from an API and writes some of the data to a spreadsheet, seems simple enough.

However I am running into a problem, basically, the request receives a 404 error whenever I try and put a variable into the URL. However if I set the URL directly, it works perfectly!

For example, I am retrieving numbers from a from a database which should be inserted into the url variable, using the following code:

```
url = 'https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/{}/charges'.format(number)
```

When I try and use this URL in the request, using this code:

```
r = requests.get(url, auth=('**API CODE**', ''))
```

I get a 404 request and therefore don't get a nice JSON returned. What's weird is that when I track the URL variable using PyCharm, the URL seems correct.

However the mystery deepens when I run the exact same code but set the URL definitively, using the following code:

```
url = 'https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/123456/charges'
```

It all works perfectly and I get a JSON in return. Essentially, using a variable in the URL leads to a 404 error.

I thought this had something to do with encoding or perhaps the variable still being an integer so I have tried solving that using the following code but with still no luck:

```
url = str(url)
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what's causing this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Print out the value for url after `url = 'https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/{}/charges'.format(number)` to see if it is what you think it should be.

Comment: If the value of `url` looks good, there may be a hidden character (non-printable) that is part of number.  Where does that come from?  To test, set `number = 123456` right before your `url` setting.  That should work and would further lead to the likelihood of it being a hidden character.

Comment: Hi @sberry, thanks for the reply, yeah your suggestion does work so the problem seems to be in the numbers variable and not the URL. I am using the CSV module to read the numbers data from a CSV file i have. Do you know how i can get rid of hidden characters in the string?

Comment: Maybe you just need to use `.trim()` to remove whitespace around it.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, thanks for the response, just tried .strip() as trim didn't work but still no luck.

Comment: There must be something different in the URL. How you create a variable doesn't matter, only its contents.